# Want to set background color of my menu item

Tags: html, css, background-color, menuitem

Here is my HTML code:

```
<nav id="nav">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#"> Home </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#"> About Us </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#"> Photos </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#"> Contact </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

what code should I do for changing its background colour?

Comment: There is nothing here we can use to help you. Please include your CSS and HTML markup. EDIT - It looks as if you improperly formatted your question. I went in and edited the HTML, but it is pending review. You will also need to add your CSS in order for us to help solve your problem.

Comment: <nav id="nav"><ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> About Us </a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"> Photos </a></li>
                       <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
                    </ul></nav> ...    nd my css file.. #nav, #nav ul{
    background-color: #ccc000;    
}  its not working

Comment: Do you want the entire list a certain background color or just a certain item?  And if so, which item?

Comment: @DeependraSinghNathawat Don't post you code in the comments section. You can edit your post above.

Comment: Want to change menu item's background color

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: i just want to change the backgound color... thats all. Why this site is so complicated?

Comment: @DeependraSinghNathawat This site has rules in place to make sure that not only do the users asking questions get the answers they need, but also people who are searching for those same answers. Questions like yours that show little code are of no use to those seeking answers. If the rules of this site are too complicated for you, then you might be better off finding another resource. Also, you have a perfectly good answer below that, despite the lack of information provided, describes in detail how to achieve what you want.

Comment: thank you for such kind of information.

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't provide nearly enough information. However, from your bullet list I can assume you are using  and/or

tags, like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>About Us</li>
   <li>Photos</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

The most efficient way to color the backgrounds of your elements is to use CSS styles. In a CSS file you will want to use a selector to select the

elements within your .

```
ul li {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

This CSS code will change the background color of each element. However, if you have multiple lists and don't want them all to have a blue background, you must give your  a class in your HTML file.

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>About Us</li>
   <li>Photos</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Then in your CSS code you will be able to target the "nav" class directly.

```
#nav li {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Hope this helps. In the future, provide more details about your code and question.

Comment: +1 Good answer/explanation. Just a heads up, you can view what the user typed in by clicking the "edit" link under their post. This will allow you see any improperly formatted markup.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. At the time of writing my answer he hadn't provided any code.